# Numba save permutations with duplicates

Tags: python, permutation, combinatorics, numba

I have a function that gets called extremely often and so to speed it up i want to use numbas `@njit` decorator. However in this function i need to calculate the permutations of an array and numba does not play nice with itertools.

I found [this](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3599) for a numba save version to produce permutations however this implementation does not deal with duplicates in the input in the way i need it to.

```
array1 = [9,9,21]
def permutations(A, k):
    r = [[i for i in range(0)]]
    for i in range(k):
        r = [[a] + b for a in A for b in r if (a in b)==False]
    return r
print(permutations(array1,3))
print(list(itertools.permutations(array1,3)))

[]
[(9, 9, 21), (9, 21, 9), (9, 9, 21), (9, 21, 9), (21, 9, 9), (21, 9, 9)]
```

What i want is the second result, not the first

Comment: Can you share the input, output and code you have done

Comment: `itertools.permutations` is written in C so a Numba version of the same will not be faster. See the source code here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1863302d61a7a5dd8b8d345a00f0ee242c7c10bf/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L3258

Comment: @DeepakTripathi i edited the comment with the iterative permutation solution that i have that (obviously) doesnt work with duplicates. and then the result from itertools.permutations that gives the desired result.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin i know that numba wont speed up the permutations part. but the function has multiple other things happening and would be sped up significantly in total. I have already done that with the above function for a slightly different case where no duplicates occur

Comment: @J.N. what is array1 ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi oops, added it in.

Comment: So you want duplicates in your result or you don';t want duplicates ? `[(9, 9, 21), (9, 21, 9), (9, 9, 21), (9, 21, 9), (21, 9, 9), (21, 9, 9)]` this contains duplicates

Comment: in the totally ideal world i would have multiset partitions that giveme [(9,9,21),(9,21,9),(21,9,9)] but that is even more complicated to do. For now i would be happy with just having the same result as itertools.permutations when i have duplicates in my input. However the answer from the github issue gives a completely empty array in such cases.

Comment: I would try to identify what can be sped up with Numba before rewriting a custom implementation of permutations. It sounds like your function can be split in smaller functions that could then perhaps benefit from Numba.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of understanding, but will lru_cache work for this function? As the number just repeats itself in different arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

I've created your "ideal world" permutations function, it recursively sends one permutation of the original list with one member short.
However, don't expect as fast results as in itertools.

```
array1 = [9, 9, 21]
array2 = [1, 2, 3]
array3 = [1, 2, 3, 4]


def permutations(A):

    r = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        a, b = A[i], A[: i] + A[i + 1:]
        if b:
            for c in permutations(b):
                if [a] + c in r:
                    continue
                r.append([a] + c)
        else:
            r.append([a])
    return r


print(permutations(array1))
print(permutations(array2))
print(permutations(array3))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[9, 9, 21], [9, 21, 9], [21, 9, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3, 2], 
 [2, 1, 3, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 1, 3], [2, 4, 3, 1], 
 [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 2, 1, 4], [3, 2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1], 
 [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2], [4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3, 1], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
```